# mean coefficient and amplitude of a sine curve

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following equation $$f(x) = m - A~\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{P}~x\right)$$ and I know the value of the positive area and the negative area (eg. $m=0$ means: positive = negative); how can I calculate $m$ and $A$?

thanks

Comment: What is the domain of your function? i.e. over what domain do you compute the area?

Comment: the domain is [0:365], a year.